# How do I understand "victís" and "imperitátum" in this sentence from Livy XXI?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, grammar-identification

In *Róma Æterna* (second volume of *Lingua Latína per sé illustráta*), p. 209, in a discussion of Hannibal adapted from Livy book XXI, contains the following sentence:

> Odiís etiam prope májóribus certávérunt quam víribus, Rómánís indignantibus quod victóribus victí ultró ínferrent arma, Pœnís quod superbé aváréque créderent imperitátum victís esse.

I'm confused both by *victís* and by *imperitátum* (though more by the latter than the former).

My impulse would be to make the infinitive *victós esse*, with an implied *sé* somewhere in there, so that it would agree with the accusative + infinitive construction. I can easily imagine, though, that *victís* has been attracted by *Pœnís* into the ablative. If that's not what's going on, though, does anybody have any ideas?

More confusing to me (or at least less productive of possible explanations) is *imperitátum*. The only neuter noun in the sentence is *arma*, which doesn't match in number (and also *arma imperitáta* doesn't make any sense), so if it's a participle I don't see what it could be referring to. But there aren't any verbs of motion, so it can't be a supine either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one piece of the puzzle you're missing is that *impero* takes a dative for the person being commanded: this explains *victis*, as agreeing with an implied "them" (*sibi*).

*Imperitatum* is an impersonal passive: literally, "they believed it to have been commanded to them", i.e. "they believed they had been commanded". The syntactic issue here is that since *impero* takes a dative object, it can't be passivized normally, so this impersonal construction has to be used instead.

Comment: AH! So a clunky, literal translation would be something like, "because they believed it had been haughtily and greedily commanded to them having been conquered" —> "because they believed they had been commanded haughtily and greedily once they were conquered." *Imperitátum* is like Cæsar's *ventum est* or *pugnátum est*. There's an implied *esse* here, so *imperitátum* is the accusative infinitive—it's just being used impersonally.